# How to calculate expiry date when manufacturing date and best before month is given in database

Tags: java, mysql, date

I have a database that hold the value of manufacturing date and best before month where date is given in format of 'YYYY-MM-DD'. 
For example date of manufacturing is 2014-01-09 and best before month given is 12 month or it could be 11 month as given in database. whenever i try retrieving dates from database it gives exception as Bad format for DATE '12' in column 2.

What I tried is

```
public void calculateExpiryDate(List<Item> items) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    List<Item> ItemList1 = new ArrayList<Item>();
    String query = "select mfg_date,UseBeforeInMonths from cheese_tbl";
    PreparedStatement prepStmt = null;
    try {
        prepStmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
    } catch (SQLException e2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        rs = prepStmt.executeQuery();
    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }  

      try {
        while (rs.next()) {
            Item i1=new Item();
            java.sql.Date dbSqlDate = rs.getDate(2);
            i1.setManufacturingDate(rs.getDate("mfg_date"));
            i1.setManufacturingDate(rs.getDate("UseBeforeInMonths"));


            ItemList.add(i1);
        }
    System.out.println(ItemList1);
      }
      catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }




}
```

But this gives me bad format for date

Can any one help me with calculating expiry date of product.
Thank you.

Comment: how can be the number '12' a value with the format 'YYYY-MM-DD'? either best before is a month or is a string with format 'YYYY-MM-DD'.

Comment: @Paolo sorry.. date is having format as 'YYYY-MM-DD'

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to give the manufacturing date in YYY-MM-DD format, and store the time till the "best before date" in a number of months.

I'd store that duration in an integer and use the Jodatime api (http://www.joda.org/joda-time/ or if you use Java SE8 http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html) to calculate the best before date.

This works as follows :

```
LocalDateTime manufacturingDate = new LocalDateTime(rs.getDate("mfg_date"));
LocalDateTime bestBefore = manufacturingDate.plusMonths(rs.getInt("UseBeforeInMonths"));
```

Hope this helps.